# How to find the current time slot matches with any of the table field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I've 34 boolean fields in DailyAvailability table

```
TimeSlot1, TimeSlot2, .....TimeSlot34
```

curreponding to 34 time slots

```
07:00AM-07:30AM, 07:30AM-08:00AM, .... , 11:30PM-12:00PM
```

How can I get the records that matches with the present time slot say 3:30PM-4:00PM (need to construct it from `GETDATE()` or with `DATEDIFF`)

Issue is that the TimeSlot1 are simple boolean fields and has no actually mapped to time.

Current query is

```
SELECT *
FROM DailyAvailability  
WHERE Present  = 1 
    AND AvailDate = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),120),10) 
    AND ... // TimeSlotX = 1
```

How can I implement the last AND in the WHERE part?

Dynamic SQL?

Comment: How do you know that Timeslot1 means 7-730? I suppose redesigning the table is out of the question?

Comment: @podiluska That is the issue, how can I map Timeslot1 with 7:30 slot with SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select  (((datepart(HOUR,getdate())-6)*2)-1)+
         case when datepart(MI,getdate())>30 then 1 
              else 0 end [timeSlot_number]
```

This Query will give the current time slot number, Starting with 7-7:30 AM as TimeSlot 1

Comment: Could you please explain so that I can rework on it. For the time `2012-07-27 16:50:53.750` your code give `11`, but the actual timeslot is `20`

Comment: @Mithun: I forgot to multiply it by 2,as each hour has two parts. I will update my qury

Comment: Yeah, slot number is correct now. Can you please explain the use of `[timeSlot_number]` at the end of the query

Comment: @Mithun: [timeSlot_number] is just a name given to the output column.. You can give any name there

Answer (score 1):

If it is at all possible, I'd recommend changing your table design. As you're discovering, this structure is hard to query. It's also inflexible.  Solving this particular issue is only going to lead to more issues later.